# How to get the position of a specific value in result list?

Tags: mysql

Here, I'm getting a list of hotels grouped by their types and ordered by the number of room available.

```
SELECT hotel_type, SUM(room_available) room_available FROM history WHERE hotel_name = 'anyHotel' GROUP BY hotel_type ORDER BY room_available DESC
```

I wish to get the position (number of line) of the first line where `hotel_type='Classic'` that appears in this list.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `rank()` and a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select hotel_type, sum(room_available) room_available,
        rank() over(order by sum(room_available) desc) rn
    from history 
    where hotel_name = 'anyHotel' 
    group by hotel_type 
) t
where hotel_type = 'Classic'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! May God bless you and your family.